# MS Project - Assign a resource to multiple tasks that take place on the same day

Tags: project, ms-project

I have a number of tasks that all are 1 day in duration and take place on the same day. I want to assign a resource to these tasks but only have it calculate for 1 day - it currently calculates 8 hours for each task (even though they're on the same day) for the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert the "Work" column. Do this BEFORE you assign resources to the task. Let us assume that you have 4 one -day tasks--all on same day--and you wish to have "Bob" Work on these tasks. So, enter "2 Hours" in the Work column for all 4 tasks. THEN, assign Bob to all 4 tasks. Bob's total Work for the day will be 8 hours.